# Using reflection return a list of objects from Property.GetValue

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to retrieve a list of objects when using the PropertyInfo.GetValue method.
I do not know what type of list it will be.  My code looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Error> FindErrors(object obj)
    {
        var errors = new List<Error>();

        errors.AddRange(Validate(obj));


        List<PropertyInfo> properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsByRef).ToList();


        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (IsList(p))
            {
                // This line is incorrect?  What is the syntax to get this to be correcT?????
                List<object> objects = p.GetValue(obj, null);

                foreach (object o in objects)
                {
                    errors.AddRange(FindErrors(o));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errors.AddRange(FindErrors(p.GetValue(obj, null)));
            }
        }


        return errors;
    }
```

My problem is I am not sure what the syntax should be to get that List because that line of code is currently incorrect.  How can I get that list of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that every `List<T>` is a `List<object>`. You should probably check whether the type implements the **non-generic** `IList` and use that instead:

```
var objects = p.GetValue(obj, null) as IList;
if(objects != null) {...}
```

You can `foreach` etc over an `IList`

Comment: Hi Marc!  Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!  It seems to work perfectly.

Comment: IList giving an error here, "Using geberşc type IList requires 1 type arguments". I'm trying to use it as non-generic but it wants me to put generic

Comment: @AsIndeed make sure you've found the non-generic interface, then! There are 2: `IList` and `IList<T>` - in different namespaces. Happy to help more but I'd need some code.

Comment: `var objects = p.GetValue(obj, null) as IList;` gives me `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter count mismatch.'`, are we missing something ?

Comment: @djack109 are you perhaps accessing an "indexer" property, i.e. how you'd use as `obj["Foo"]` ? if so: you'll need to include the index parameters; if not, try `p.GetValue(obj)`

Comment: Yeah I had to detect if it was a IList and then do something different